# How to process large nested arrays is Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From a flat table I create a dataframe with this schema:

```
|-- Activity_A1: string (nullable = true)
|-- Activity_A2: string (nullable = true)
|-- Details: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- Agreement_A1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Agreement_A2: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- Lines: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- Line_A1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- Line_A2: string (nullable = true)
```

## Data

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Activity_A1|Activity_A2|Details                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Act1_Attr1 |Act1_Attr2 |[[Agr2_Attr1,Agr2_Attr2,WrappedArray([Line3_Attr1,Line3_Attr2]),WrappedArray([Stage1_Attr1,Stage1_Attr2])], [Agr1_Attr1,Agr1_Attr2,WrappedArray([Line2_Attr1,Line2_Attr2], [Line1_Attr1,Line1_Attr2]),WrappedArray([Stage1_Attr1,Stage1_Attr2])]]                             |
|Act2_Attr1 |Act2_Attr2 |[[Agr4_Attr1,Agr4_Attr2,WrappedArray([Line6_Attr1,Line6_Attr2]),WrappedArray([Stage4_Attr1,Stage5_Attr2])], [Agr3_Attr1,Agr3_Attr2,WrappedArray([Line5_Attr1,Line5_Attr2], [Line4_Attr1,Line4_Attr2]),WrappedArray([Stage2_Attr1,Stage2_Attr2], [Stage3_Attr1,Stage3_Attr2])]]|
|Act3_Attr1 |Act3_Attr2 |[[Agr5_Attr1,Agr5_Attr2,WrappedArray([Line7_Attr1,Line7_Attr2]),WrappedArray([Stage6_Attr1,Stage6_Attr2])]]                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From that dataframe I try to create an instance of an object (Request class - a third-party class) for each row.
Currently my code looks like this:

## Scala

```
val ds = df.map(row => new MapResult().apply(row))(Encoders.bean(classOf[Request]))
```

## Java

```
public Request apply(Row row) {
    Request request = new Request();
    Activity act = new Activity();
    act.A1 = row.getAs("Activity_A1");
    act.A2 = row.getAs("Activity_A2");
    request.activity = act;

    List<Row> details = row.getList(row.fieldIndex("Details"));
    for (Row rowDet: details) {
        Agreement agr = new Agreement();
        agr.A1 = row.getAs("Agreement_A1");
        agr.A2 = row.getAs("Agreement_A2");
        request.agreements.add(agreement);

        List<Row> lines = rowDet.getList(rowDet.fieldIndex("Lines"));
        for (Row line: lines){              
            Line ln = new Line();
            ln.A1 = row.getAs("Line_A1");
            ln.A2 = row.getAs("Line_A2");
            agreement.getLines().add(ln);           
        }
    }   
    return request;
}
```

An array of lines with 10000 elements processes for 10 seconds, 100_000 takes 30 minutes to process, which is too long. The largest Activity has more than 450_000 lines takes more than 7 hours to complete.

Is there any way how I can do this transformation more efficiently?

Comment: You need to divide this nested data(at least the inner nested arrays) into another dataframe

Comment: But I can't use another dataframe inside my apply function, can I?